# Flutter use SliverAppBar with Hero widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I'm having trouble using the Hero widget with `SliverAppBar`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow]
              .map((e) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => ScrollPage(color: e),
                          ));
                    },
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: e,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        color: e,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollPage({super.key, required this.color});

  final Color color;

  @override
  State<ScrollPage> createState() => _ScrollPageState();
}

class _ScrollPageState extends State<ScrollPage> {
  // final GlobalKey key = GlobalKey<SliverState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          Hero(
            tag: widget.color,
            child: SliverAppBar.large(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              expandedHeight: 200,
              backgroundColor: widget.color,
              title: const Text(
                'This is a title blblaa',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
              childCount: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting error like:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6405 pos 12: 'renderObject.child == child': is not true.
```

and

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6369 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.
framework.dart:6369
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
```

and sometimes:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I did similar not using Appbar and I achieved it. Demo video [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRX2V.jpg). But, I really want to use SliverAppbar in this case.

Full minimal reproducible project: https://github.com/iqfareez/flutter_hero_sliver

How do I make the SliverAppBar work with Hero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here `Hero` is a general widget rather than a sliver-widget. That's the issue occurs while wrapping the `SliverAppBar`  with `Hero` widget.

You can do

```dart
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Hero(
    tag: widget.color,
    child: // customAppBar but it might loss the scroll-effect,
```

Also, you can wrap the `Scaffold` with Hero widget, but it will show a little different animation.

You can create `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

Check the [pr](https://github.com/iqfareez/flutter_hero_sliver/pull/1) and commit difference.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollPage({super.key, required this.color});

  final Color color;

  @override
  State<ScrollPage> createState() => _ScrollPageState();
}

class _ScrollPageState extends State<ScrollPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: MySliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(widget.color)),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              ),
              childCount: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySliverPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final tag;

  MySliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(this.tag);
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Hero(
      tag: tag,
      child: Material(
        color: tag,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              child: const Text(
                'This is a title blblaa',
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 200;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the **Hero** widget outside of the **SliverAppBar**, wrapping it around the entire **CustomScrollView**. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Hero(
        tag: 'row',
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow]
                .map((e) => GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (_) => ScrollPage(color: e),
                            ));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        color: e,
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollPage({super.key, required this.color});

  final Color color;

  @override
  State<ScrollPage> createState() => _ScrollPageState();
}

class _ScrollPageState extends State<ScrollPage> {
  // final GlobalKey key = GlobalKey<SliverState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Hero(
        tag: 'row',
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              expandedHeight: 200,
              backgroundColor: widget.color,
              title: const Text(
                'This is a title blblaa',
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                ),
                childCount: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I want to achieve. See this [video](https://imgur.com/SuuL0D4). (Slow animation to show clarity). I also edited the question by adding repo link.